# Why MainWindow in Qt is closing after start the program?

Tags: linux, qt, qmainwindow

I was working on Windows with this program and was ok..
When im running it on linux (using QT creator, same on windows) window show and hide immediately. 
The program is to big to paste it all, this is my main.cpp code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show(); 
    return a.exec();
}
```

What should it be?

Comment: Without showing us the code for MainWindow, it's hard to say...

Comment: At least show the MainWindow Constructor code

Answer (score 0):

If there is no fatal exception that exits the app then the event loop (a.exec()) is quitting due to some event served. So, the visibility is not enough to conclude why your app is quitting on Linux.

Comment: I would look at the Application Output console in Qt Creator and watch the log, it may have valuable hints there. Also, we need to trace MainWindow destructor, why it is called? Also void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent * event), what makes it to close prematurely?